# How print only price in this list using python and access to it

Tags: python, list, dictionary

this list in python:

```
lis=[{'OriginId': 1362, 'DestinationId': 1422, 'QuoteIds': [1], 'Price': 755.0, 'QuoteDateTime': '2018-12-19T09:18:00'}]
```

I want to print only the price in this list how can i do ?

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: figure out what is the `type` of data inside that list. then read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list with one element which is a dictionary.

- Lists are defined with `[]` and accessed with and index `A[0]`.
- Dictionaries are defined with `{}`. Dictionaries hold a *key -> value* pair
  and are accessed with `['key']` (single or double quote).

To answer your question:

```
A = [{'OriginId': 1362, 'DestinationId': 1422, 'QuoteIds': [1], 'Price': 755.0, 'QuoteDateTime': '2018-12-19T09:18:00'}]

print(A[0]['Price'])
```